# How to run BackgroundWorker in UserControl in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am having problem in running BackgroundWorker in UserControl for downloading some content from server. My problem is this that when I write the following code the UserControl get returns to main form and downloading does not get started.

```
public AdFeeds()
        {
                InitializeComponent();
                bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
                bgWorker.DoWork += bgWorker_DoWork;
                bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
 void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            DownloadWallpaper();
        }
```

For downloading wallpaper I am using the following code

```
public static void DownloadWallpaper()
        {
            try
            {

                DataSet dsFile = Global.ReadConfig;
                XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(dsFile.Tables[0].Rows[0][9].ToString());//Environment.CurrentDirectory+@"..\..\..\App_Data\Wallpaper.xml");//(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "\\Wallpaper\\Themes.xml");
                string s = xDoc.Root.Name.ToString();
                var countNode = xDoc.Root.Elements().Count();

                for (int i = 0; i < countNode; i++)
                {
                    XNode childNode = xDoc.Root.Nodes().ElementAt(i);
                    XElement ele = (XElement)childNode;
                    path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "\\Wallpaper\\Banner\\" + ele.Name;



                    DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                    var movieList = from a in xDoc.Root.Descendants(ele.Name).Elements()
                                    select new Ad()
                                    {
                                        Path = ele.Name.ToString(),
                                        Link = a.Value
                                    };
                    foreach (var a in movieList)
                    {
                        Global.filedownload(dsFile.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString() + "/Banner/" + ele.Name + "/", path + "\\");
                        advertisement.Add(a);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch 
            {

            }
        }
```

I want that user control to be initialized when the main form is initialized so I wait till the content of the user control downloaded my UI is getting locked till the content gets downloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the event after `AdFeeds` has been loaded. To do this, start the worker in the `Loaded` event handler.

```
public AdFeeds()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Loaded += OnLoaded;
}

private async void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Loaded -= OnLoaded;

    await Task.Run(()=>
    {
        DownloadWallpaper();
    });
}
```

Also, no need to use a Background worker. You can just use a simple `Task`, and `await` it.

Comment: It worked for me but still I am having an issue with this. I want to update UI whenever wallpaper folder is downloaded but with this code my UI is updating when the entire folders of wallpaper kept on server is downloaded.

Comment: I think you should post new question as you have got your answer.